# AWS SES subdomain email

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, mx-record, dkim, amazon-ses

Can I add CNAME and MX records to a subdomain hosted outside Amazon to work with AWS SES?

I have bill@example.com and jill@example.com.

- I would like to leave bill as is while transferring jill over to use with AWS services. Can this be done?
- Would I create a subdomain (eg. jill@aws.example.com) to handle sending and receiving with Amazon?
- Would I be able to verify this subdomain with Amazon and add an MX record to the appropriate server (feedback-smtp.aws-region.amazonses.com)?
- Would I want to migrate a subdomain to Route53 and work with their hosted zones(this seems expensive)?

Thanks for reading and looking forward to discussions!

Comment: I have formatted your question and changed the title a bit, but your question is still somewhat unclear. In general subdomains and email can have different hosts, and what I think you're trying to do should be possible. Please edit your question for clarity if you would like more help.

Comment: This sounds like a "how do I solve X" when Y is the problem kind of question... My understanding of SES is it's for mailblasting, like Mailchimp is. Not a great solution for actually hosting email for `jill`. Also Route53 is really not expensive -  $0.50 a month for up to 25 domains per account, then $0.40 per million requests? How popular is your domain?